# My update manager always stuck while applying changes

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Update Manager getting stuck unless I hit 'q'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57869/why-is-update-manager-getting-stuck-unless-i-hit-q)

My update manager always stuck while applying changes. It stucks until i manually press <kbd>q</kbd> to complete applying changes

The picture illustrate more.

[image: update-manager]

Comment: Can you post the errors shown in the above same window.

Comment: It just stucks here only if you press q key it will finish the update as usual

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in Terminal , and post the reported errors if any ,in your question

Comment: to me that looks like some changelog/text file displayed using less (why should a package do that?). If that's the case, try clicking into the "black area" and hit the `q` key (to leave the "less" program). Update should then continue.

Comment: @IZZY yeah that true but i dont want to press q every time i want to update

Comment: @maythux understood -- but IMHO it is a one-time thing (if that specific package was updated, it should be over). Did you try it? You didn't say you're always pressing "q" here and no longer can stand it :)

Answer (score 1):

I am on ubuntu 12.04 and have this problem since 10.04, it looks like none cares to solve it, and is one of the things that makes ubuntu not user friendly, once one should not open terminal nor hit q to solve it, nor do what I do.

My solution, after many different methods is the following:

1. use the update manager only to fast-check if there is any new update.
2. if there is, close update manager (once it will get stuck if you continue with it), and open synaptic package manager (install it if you don't have it).
3. hit the buttons on the top side one by one (reload, mark all upgrades, apply)

you will notice, that every time an update would like to show you changelog, it will, but this time with a 'close' button there. Close every changelog that might appear and it will continue fine.

Comment: I will not post ever again because my post was edited. I consider this rude.

Comment: You can always rollback the edit by clicking on the "edited ....." link